# Adding 2 simple number together in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want a very simple batch file that allows me to add to number together
i was  thinking something like

```
@echo off
Set /a number1=enter a number
Set /a number2=enter your second number
set /a sum1==%number1%+%number2%
echo your fist numer was %number1% and your second number was %number2%
echo When you add them both together you get %sum1% hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
pause
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use /p to prompt for input

```
@echo off
Set /p number1=Enter a number: 
Set /p number2=Enter your second number:
set /a sum1=%number1%+%number2%
echo your fist numer was %number1% and your second number was %number2%
echo When you add them both together you get %sum1% hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
Set /p numbera=Enter a number: 
Set /p numberb=Enter a second number: 
set /a sum=numbera+numberb
echo your fist numer was %numbera% and your second number was %numberb%
echo When you add them both together you get %sum% hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
pause>nul
```

I think this method looks cleaner. use set /p for input, and use = not == for setting variables. here is an example.

```
set x=2
set y=3
set /a z=x+y+2
echo z is equal to %z%
pause>nul
```

the output should be `z is equal to 7`. as you can see, `x+y+2` looks more like math than `%x%+%y%+2`. 
if I missed something in my explanation, comment and I will fix it. please mark as correct answer if this helped so I can know that I answered the question.

; ) have fun!!

Comment: Can you edit to show an example of how to use the variable setting method mentioned?